# grep'ing through mailq

Tags: postfix, shell, grep

I want to filter some of the mail IDs returned by `mailq` (Postfix). However, the format is not very "grep-friendly", since the information for a *single* mail spans *multiple* lines:

```
  9F701869D2     1356 Mon Aug 23 12:13:43  some@sender
  (host some.host[1.2.3.4] said: 450 4.1.1 some error message)
                                           some@recipient

  9437586CF4     3153 Sat Aug 21 09:36:40  some@other.sender
  (host some.host[1.2.3.4] said: 450 4.1.1 some error message)
                                           some@other.recipient
```

What's the easiest way to get, for example, all mail IDs where some particular error code occurred? Maybe by removing the (single) newlines, then `grep`ing and then `cut`ing? Or by using some other, more suitable tool?

Please explain your answer. My main interest is not a copy-and-paste solution for my current problem (filtering by error code), but rather understanding how to easily parse such multi-line output.

Comment: awk is the tool you want.

Comment: @Paul: Since `awk` has quite a learning curve, could you provide a small example for mailq parsing as an answer?

Comment: In the postsuper man page there is an example of using awk to parse the mailq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

grep -C 1 said:

-C is context and returns one line before & after "said:".  Also, for future reference, -A is for after, -B is for before.

grep -C 1 said: | grep ^[0-9] | cut -f1 -d  " "

(for the list of IDs)

If you need something more complex, then you would have to use awk.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Perl and the [Postfix::Parse::Mailq](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Postfix-Parse-Mailq-1.001/lib/Postfix/Parse/Mailq.pm) module.
If you don't know Perl it won't be very easy to right the good script but feel free to ask help.
If you are interested on how the module parse the output check [the source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RJBS/Postfix-Parse-Mailq-1.001/lib/Postfix/Parse/Mailq.pm)

Comment: Thanks, that will be useful once I need to parse for more complex things!

Answer (score 1):

**apq** is a concise way to parse mailq or postqueue:

https://github.com/alexjurkiewicz/apq

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can figure out something to use to isolate the sender or receiver address, mailq can be parsed using awk:

```
mailq | grep @ | awk {'print $7'}
```